# Why does `consteval` not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++20, constexpr, consteval

```
inline consteval unsigned char operator""_UC(const unsigned long long n)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(n);
}

inline consteval char f1(auto const octet)
{
    return char(octet >> 4_UC);
}

inline constexpr char f2(auto const octet)
{
    return char(octet >> 4_UC);
}

int main()
{
    auto c1 = f1('A'); // ok
    auto c2 = f2('A'); // error

    return c1 + c2;
}
```

Compiled with: `clang++-14 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++`, and the error message is:

```
undefined reference to `operator"" _UC(unsigned long long)'
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WarbWYcfP)

**Why does** `f1()` **is ok while** `f2()` **is not?**

**Why does** `consteval` **not behave as expected?**

Comment: Looks like a Clang bug to me. Consider reporting it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It had already been reported: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of clang 14 and has been fixed.

See: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/ca844ab01c3f9410ceca967c09f809400950beae